# Very low quality flags

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, low-quality-posts

I have an issue with a decision to decline a flag I raised yesterday.
On the late answer queue I had to review [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43403064/gradient-descent-for-linear-regression-one-variable-in-octave/57341200#57341200) answer.

At the time it didn't even have this text:

> Please try this (Linear 
>   Regression w/one variable):

It was just a snippet of code, without any explanation of any kind.

So I flagged it as a **low quality** answer.

However this was declined with the reason given

> flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

Now I don't know anything about MATLAB. I couldn't even tell if the answer is correct.

I stand by my judgment that this answer is a low quality one. Am I wrong? If so, what would qualify as a low quality answer?

Comment: Very Low Quality (VLQ) does not mean: this post is badly formatted or this is a bad answer. VLQ should only be used for things that *just need deleting* because it is nonsense, or a post in a foreign language or similar. It’s the *this is just a pile of something random that was left in the entryway of the flat and now everyone has to step over it until the janitor cleans it away* equivalent, and VLQ is your way of calling the janitor.

Comment: Note that *if a post is salvageable by editing* it should not be flagged as VLQ.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Now I don't know anything about matlab. I couldn't even tell if the answer is correct.

Then you are probably not in a position to be judging the quality of the answer. The answer posted *is* an answer, and it does not appear to be of the highest quality, but I wouldn't call it "Low Quality", especially if it is technically correct.  In fact, on reviewing the answer myself, it doesn't look that bad at all: they post code, and they explain what the code is trying to do.

Please check out [this answer on the main meta site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/221157/162852) for some discussions on what constitutes a "very-low-quality" answer.

Comment: As I said in my post, at the time of the review there wasn't any explanation. I was added 6 hours **after** my review. It was just a snippet of code left on a question with an already accepted answer.
If I was to answer to a question with a regex without any explanation about what it does, would this be considered high quality ? Seems weird to me.

Comment: I reviewed the link in your answer. It seems I was wrong about what constitute a good or bad quality answer. I'll keep that in mind in the future.